# How to take a random n sized elements from a list that aren't specific elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

From a list, I have to take `quantity` sized list of random elements and turn that into another list named `sample`.  This is what I have:

```
used = [element1.png, element2.png]

sample = random.sample(os.listdir(current_dir + '/Logos/'), quantity)
```

How can I make sure that this random sample does not have any item from `used`? Instead of a bulky if statement, is it possible to do this in a single line?

Comment: Why would it be bulky to use an if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your population into a set, and take the difference with set(used).  Then take the sample from that difference result.

```
sample = random.sample(
             list(set(os.listdir(current_dir + '/Logos/')) - set(used)),
             quantity)
```

Comment: Clever solution but take note of the deprecation warning that sampling from a set is deprecated in 3.9 and will be removed in the future. You could wrap the set in `list()`.

Comment: Good idea.
I added `list` for hardiness.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC maybe try a simple `list` comprehension:

```
used = ['element1.png', 'element2.png']
sample = random.sample([i for i in os.listdir(current_dir + '/Logos/') if i not in used], quantity)
```

And now:

```
print(sample)
```

Would give the expected result.